# How can I open an MS Word document and set the insertion point in Perl?

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl and I want to open a Word document in the MS Word application with cursor pointing the location specified by me. Is it possible to implement this requirement in Perl?

Answer (score 1):

The [Win32::OLE](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-OLE) module can help with scripting Word and other Windows apps in Perl.

I found a code example of how it's used at [René Nyffenegger's OLE tutorial](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/perl/word.html).